# array in conditional statement for member level, Paid Memberships Pro, not working

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I want to update a custom plugin that uses Paid Memberships Pro so that it shows a form on a page only to members at levels 3 or 4.

Currently the function (shows a form) only to users at level 3.

If I swap out "3" for "4" it works perfectly for member levels at 4.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
$userID = get_current_user_id();
if (pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(3, $userID)) {
```

I know what I want is an array but I think the $userID after the number 3 is throwing me off. I've tried variations but don't know the correct syntax to make this right. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used pmpro, but here what you're asking for

> show a form on a page only to members at levels 3 or 4

It seems to me that you could just add an `or` to your `if` statement, like so:

```
 if ( pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(3, $userID) || pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(4, $userID) ) {
```

Comment: YES that's it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: If I wanted to add a 3rd level of membership, would this same or statement work?  I tried it but clearly didn't get it to work for the 3rd member userID.